# Address to receive a message on an AMQP header exchange

Tags: amqp, qpid

What is the address I should use to binding to a queue to a header exchange using Qpid? I want the queue to only receive messages that have a specific header and value?

Answer (score 0):

drain -f "qName ; { create:receiver , node: { durable:False, x-declare: {auto-delete:'false', type:headers}, x-bindings:[{arguments:{x-matc​h:any, 'header1':'value1'},key:qName,​ queue:qName, exchange:'amqmatch'}]}}"

If your address doesn’t look like this, it will not work. I got an error saying that x-match needed to be included even when I included it.

AMQP Broker: Qpid 0.12